# Having issues with C++ Function pointers in COM

Tags: c++, com

There is one thing that bothers me, C++ function pointers. I'm asking this question because I'm trying to implement callback functions used in my game engine. The issue is, for example:

```
// Callback function
HRESULT RenderScene(float fps){ HRESULT hr; return S_OK; }

// Set the message
msk->SetMessage(0, SM_RENDERSCENE, (void*) RenderScene);
```

The problem is COM doesn't allow function pointers in their member functions. Also, doesn't allow for polymorphism. As you can see, I made it a void*. Fine with me because I know what the callback function is. The main issue is that I want something that is type-safe.
Now say if the user doesn't know the callback function declaration. For example,

```
// Callback function
HRESULT CALLBACK RenderScene() or RenderScene(int fps) or RenderScene(int a, int b)
```

Is implemented in WndProc as:

```
...
SM_RENDERSCENE:
((void (_stdcall*)(float fps)) pfn)(1.0f);
break;
...
```

The first, doesn't have an argument, therefore, he doesn't see fps. The second, loses precision. The third, loses precision and has an unused argument. Do you see where I'm going at? Tried using a union but COM doesn't allow function pointers in the member function.

I tried, and tried again. Nothing works, even the MFC message maps are ugly if they didnt have those macros.

To clarify, I rather have it return an error like `E_FAIL` or `E_INVALIDFUNCTION` if the function doesn't match the specification of `SM_RENDERSCENE`.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem.

Note: I like the COM specification and I'm not going to change, so focus on the issue not about why I'm using COM. Thank you, any help will do.

Comment: ".... Also, doesn't allow for polymorphism" This is so NOT true. COM is actually based on polymorphism. I think you should do some reading about COM before getting your hands dirty with coding.

Comment: The thing to understand about COM is that it's all about interfaces. As far as COM is concerned, classes are just an implementation details. (A C++ implementation of a COM interface will of course need a class to implement those interfaces, but COM only sees the interfaces.) So polymorphism in COM isn't exactly the same as polymorphism in C++. (COM doesn't have a concept of subclass, for example.) But it's still polymorphism: in as much as many different concrete implementations can implement the same interface.

Comment: One qu: it seems you're also using windows messages here - eg. SM_RENDERSCENE looks like a message, and you're also mentioning MFC message maps, and limiting your params to two ints instead of just using a float. Windows Messages are really a separate mechanism, and shouldn't affect or limit how you use COM. You might want to explain more why/how you are using it here.

Comment: I'm just in the process of figuring out how I'm going to handle all my notifications. I don't want to use MFC or ATL, trying to keep in simple. SM stands for Scene Manger fyi. I don't want people to have to implement every single method in an interface that handlers callback functions. Only use the ones they need, less writing more programming. Who wants to put E_NOTIMPL in every method they don't use. Most of my interfaces will have atleast 15 - 30 callback functions and I don't like the idea of partitioning the interfaces.

Comment: @MatthewHooker: you do point out a good issue with interfaces: interfaces are almost by definition all-or-nothing: they're not like base classes where you can pick-and-chose and override some methods but not others. With an interface, you have to implement all methods.

Comment: Anyhow: I'm still not sure how windows messages relate to your qu. Again, it may help you to describe your overall problem as fully as possible, so that SO readers can understand the full 'big picture' here. That fact that your interfaces have a lot of methods - many of which you want to be 'optional' - is something that should be in the original qu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HRESULT RenderScene(float fps){ ...}
HRESULT CALLBACK RenderScene() or ...
Is implemented ... ((void (_stdcall*)(float fps)) pfn)(1.0f);
```

No, COM definitely supports function pointers.  It is only when you use the subset of COM Automation or need to marshal function calls that you could get in trouble.  Which is not the case here, you don't marshal between processes or threads and don't need automation since you work with only one language.

The simple problem is that you have the issue that you are trying to protect against, the function pointer definition doesn't match the implementation.  Yes, a (void*) cast will stop the compiler from complaining about it, nothing good happens at runtime.

Your first declaration has the wrong calling convention.  Using the STDMETHODIMP macro is wise.

Your second set of declarations have the wrong arguments.

The third snippet is applying an invalid function pointer cast, a cast to a function that returns void instead of HRESULT.  And assumes __stdcall even though your RenderScene() function didn't use STDMETHODIMP or CALLBACK.  Which is why you don't see a proper value for the argument.

Solve function pointer problems by declaring an alias for the pointer type:

```
 typedef HRESULT (__stdcall * RenderSceneCallback)(float fps);
```

And consistenly use RenderSceneCallback in all your declarations.  Never cast.

Comment: Actually, I'm using an IDL file. The compilier complains about having a function pointer in the argument. I didn't give you the exact function declaration. I always use the STDMETHODIMP. Those functions were just scenario. I was going to use this technique but the compilier complained about function pointers in the argument. So, thats why I put void* in there because I have no other choice. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Sigh, avoid disclosing details like this in a comment.  The obviously right thing to do in IDL is to declare an interface that has a RenderScene() method.

Comment: I understand what you suggested but I don't want an interface with 15+ methods that I have to implement. Not realistic, to have one method that your actually using and then have to implement the rest of the 14. I hope you can understand where I'm going at. I don't want the user to implement any of the interface. Just like DirectX. CreateDirect3D to create IDirect3D9 then IDirect3D9 creates IDirect3DDevice9 then so on. Thats how I want it but I really need notifications (or messages).

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  Start with an interface with only one method.

Answer (score 1):

COM is a technology that is supposed to support multiple programming languages, and not all programming languages have support for all kind of features, hence some features like function  pointers and exceptions are not (in general) supported in COM.

In the case of callbacks, usually the way to go is to define a COM interface that includes the method you need to call. You can implement this function in a COM class of your choice, and you can specify this interface as a parameter to any other COM function.

If you are using ATL for your COM implementation, here is a link on [how to add an new interface to an ATL project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9dyt26z.aspx). And you could also take a look on this article at codeproject about [COM Event Handling](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/TEventHandler.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'll take a look at the COM Event Handling. Hopefully, this could be it.

Answer (score 1):

Pass interface pointers instead of function pointers. Also there is no function overloading in COM, so use different function names. Here is a pseudocode:

```
struct IRenderScene : public IUnknown
{
  HRESULT RenderScene(); // Callback function
  HRESULT RenderSceneFps(float fps); // Callback function
  HRESULT RenderSceneAB(int a, int b); // Callback function
}

IRenderScene *renderScene = ...;
msk->SetRenderScene(renderScene); // Set the callback
```

You don't need to implement COM Event Handling (Connection Points) if it is superfluous to you.

Comment: Well the good thing is, there will only be one RenderScene. Then, possible an UpdateScene. The issue though, I would have to implement every method in that interface. For instance, if I had 15+ call funtions then I would have to pass E_NOTIMPL in every method I don't use because an interface is abstract. I'm trying to avoid this by using some other techniques. If "Connection Points" provide this kind of technique I will most defiantly give it a shot. Right now my technique works but it's not type-safe. This was actually the first thing I was going to do and I might just go back to it. Thanks.